# wkhtmltopdf crash with exception 0xc0000005

Tags: asp.net, iis, wkhtmltopdf

**PROBLEM**

I run [asp.net](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/ASP.NET) with [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) on remote machine. If application is browsed localy [pdf](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Portable_Document_Format) is rendered. If app is browsed remotely wkhtmltopdf crash with exception 0xc0000005.

Q how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

At first see [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) output - that error probably is not seen if you run command localy through [CLI](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Cmd.exe) because of different request path:

> Warning: Failed to load http://{{remote_address}}:{{port}}/

And that **remote_address** is the problem - you have good configured binding address to [IIS](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Internet_Information_Services) but local machine don't recognize request path from DNS.

Solution for that issue is bind to "app binded address" eg. **public_ip** to **remote_address** into [host file](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/):

```
{{public_ip}}  {{remote_addr}}
```

After that application will knows this path and sources.

Comment: Something similar happened in our development. The IIS machine where the web application was installed had the binding "applicationname.domain.com". This name was accessible from outside the network, but not from within the same machine. Then the process of generating the PDF was waiting forever because internally wkhtmltopdf could not reach the url for the page to render. In our case it was enough to add the entry "applicationname.domain.com" pointing to 127.0.0.1 to work correctly.

Comment: @rolivares thank you for comment - Q and what did you do?

Comment: In our case it was enough to add the entry "applicationname.domain.com" pointing to 127.0.0.1 on the server to work correctly.

Comment: Thank you, I see now "In our case it was enough" - that is right because like I write "Solution for that issue is bind to "app binded address"". :-)